# Poner como fondo el contenido de una etiqueta <img> dentro de un <div> como si fuera su fondo

Tags: css, html5, imagen

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo una pagina web que debe ser editable eso incluye la imagen de fondo de un carrusel, asi es como se debe de ver
[image]

Y ese es el codigo que uso en el carrusel

Pero ahora, para que la imagen sea editable uso este codigo

```
<div class="single-hero-slides bg-img">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img  style="background-image:inherit" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Prueba_C_Imagen1") )%>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
```

Pero asi es como se ve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se encima la imagen al texto que deberia de mostrar, ya intente meter el  codigo anterior como background image pero no funciona y ponerle propiedades transparentes pero no funciona tampoco

Este es el codigo del carrusel completo

```
 <div class="caviar-hero-slides owl-carousel">
        <!-- Single Slides -->
        <div class="single-hero-slides bg-img">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img  style="background-image:inherit" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Prueba_C_Imagen1") )%>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="hero-content">
                            <h2>
                            <asp:Label  runat="server" id="lbl_titulo1_carr" apodo="Titulo del carrusel 1"></asp:Label>
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label  runat="server" id="lbl_cont1_carr" apodo="Contenido del carrusel 1"></asp:Label>
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn caviar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Inscripción </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Single Slides -->
        <div class="single-hero-slides bg-img" style="background-image: url(../img/car2.jpg);">
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="hero-content">
                            <h2>
                                <asp:Label  runat="server" id="lbl_titulo2_carr" apodo="Titulo del carrusel 2"></asp:Label>
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label  runat="server" id="lbl_cont2_carr" apodo="Contenido del carrusel 2"></asp:Label>
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn caviar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Inscripción </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, y gracias de ante mano

Comment: Coloca el código del carrusel por favor (el original), solo lo mencionas pero no lo colocaste. Saludos.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta añadiendolo, gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 1):

Probaste con un Z-index ?  el z-index es para acomodar los niveles de visualizacion por capa, dale una class a esa imagen, y luego a esa class dale un

```
.tuclase{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

por ejemplo:

sino mandame tu codigo en un codepen y lo revisamos.

Comment: Lo voy a pobrar en seguida, muchas gracias

Comment: https://codepen.io/IAmRamc/pen/gOrpNXp

Este es el link, desafortunadamente se sigue encimando la imagen

Comment: ¿? El codigo minimo necesario ya esta ahí

Comment: No lo veo como en tu pantalla al codepen , deberias agregar el css y tambien si usas un plugin de carrousel

Comment: https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/dyMyGqm  aca tengo un pen donde utilizo un slider de bootstrap parecido a lo que precisas. por ahi te guias